# Basic OpenGL lighting question

Tags: c++, opengl, lighting

I think this is an extremely stupid and newbie question, but then I am a newbie in graphics and openGL. Having drawn a sphere and put a light source nearby, also having specified ambient light, I started experimenting with light and material values and came to a surprising conclusion: the colors which we specify with `glColor*` do not matter at all when lighting is enabled.  Instead, the equivalent is the material's ambient component. Is this conclusion correct? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the lighting is enabled, then instead of the vertex color, **the material color** *(well, colors - there are several of them for different types of response to light)* is used. Material colors are specified by `glMaterial*` functions.

If you want to reuse your code, you can use `glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL)` and `glColorMaterial(GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE)` to have your old `glColor*` calls mapped to material color automatically.

*(And please switch to shaders as fast as possible - the shader approach is both easier and more powerful)*

Comment: I have heard so much about these shaders, but I have no idea what they are. I guess I'll just have to be patient till I get to the relevant chapters of the Redbook :) Thanks for the answer

Comment: The Redbook is as outdated as the whole fixed function rendering which we're discussing. You can read it for some theory and that's it. For shader tutorials, google for Lighthouse3D. :) Also have a glance on OpenGL 2.1 or OpenGL 3 reference docs on opengl.org/documentation/specs/ - they are somewhat big, but a skim will give you a good idea how OGL works.

Comment: @Kos: If the redbook is outdated, what book would you recommend? A documentation is not a book, it's a good thing, but beginners find it hard to use the documentation directly

Comment: Learning directly from the documentation is definitely a required skill in every programmer's skill tree, but I agree that the tutorials or books make it easier for beginners to start because they shorten the time between starting to learn and seeing *something which works*, which is kind of important. However, it's equally important to keep the doc under the pillow and *try* to use it for answering one's questions.

I cannot recommend any book, but I sincerely believe that Lighthouse 3D tutorials (or others available online) should be sufficient for apprentice OpenGL-ists.

Comment: @Armen: Which version of the Redbook do you have in your possession?

Comment: @Armen: I agree with Kos, please switch to GLSL shaders. Because the FFP (fixed function pipeline) is so boring and outdated :)

Comment: @Stringer Bell: I have the seventh edition : Versions 3.0 and 3.1

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you don't use fragment shader yet. From [glprogramming.com](http://glprogramming.com/red/chapter05.html#name7):

> ```
> vertex color =
>     the material emission at that vertex + 
>     the global ambient light scaled by the materials ambient
>     property at that vertex + 
>     the ambient, diffuse, and specular contributions from all the
>     light sources, properly attenuated
> ```

So yes, vertex color is not used.

Edit: You can also look for GL lightning equation in GL specification (you have one nearby, do you? ^^)